# creating two appdomains with the same friendly name

Tags: c#, appdomain

Can anyone know what happening if we create two appdomains with the same friendly name?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("mydomain");
        var myDomain2 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("mydomain");
    }
```

As i noticed this is not throwing an exception, maybe the two local variable points to the same appdomain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The friendlyName parameter is intended to identify the domain in a
>   manner that is meaningful to humans. This string should be suitable
>   for display in user interfaces.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/47e8e141.aspx

As you can guess it could only get the user confused if you use the Friendly name in a UI

Comment: Maybe my sample is not the best, but i wanted to know what happens if i create appdomain in two threads with the same name. Back to the original sample is this two separate appdomains, just happens to the same name? (like we could have two threads with the same name)

Comment: Nothing will happen (no exceptions) as the name is just to help you to identify an app domain (that's why is called friendly name) instead of have an numeric identifier.

Comment: I was on wrong track until now, for some reasons i suspected to get back the first appdomain at the second create.... Thank your explanation.